# How to change the orientation of SimpleITK image in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, simpleitk

I used [this code](https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK/issues/387#issue-293398807) to read a series for dicom images into python

```
series_IDs = sitk.ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesIDs(data_directory)
series_file_names = sitk.ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(data_directory, series_IDs[0])
series_reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
series_reader.SetFileNames(series_file_names)
series_reader.LoadPrivateTagsOn()
image3D=series_reader.Execute()
size = image3D.GetSize()
```

currently, its orientation is the following:

[image]

I need to change the orientation to the following orientation:

[image]

Is there any command in python to be able to change the orientation of SimpleITK image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending your code to perform this I would look at building a new image from your loaded in one and then adding a custom direction to it. Althernatively ITK has a orientimage filter in the python wrapping available. This is not in simpleitk but might solve your problem

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

series_IDs = sitk.ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesIDs(data_directory)
series_file_names = sitk.ImageSeriesReader.GetGDCMSeriesFileNames(data_directory, series_IDs[0])
series_reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
series_reader.SetFileNames(series_file_names)
series_reader.LoadPrivateTagsOn()
image3D=series_reader.Execute()
size = image3D.GetSize()

#get image data
image_out = sitk.GetImageFromArray(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(img))

#setup other image characteristics
image_out.SetOrigin(img.GetOrigin())
image_out.SetSpacing(img.GetSpacing())
#set to RAI
image_out.SetDirection(tuple(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
sitk.WriteImage(image_out, 'test.mha')
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed to reorient NIfTI images (files with .nii or .nii.gz extension) and the above solution didn't work for me. After some research in the SimpleITK library I found the function `sitk.DICOMOrient()` which worked for me.

Adjusting to your example (Tested in version `2.1.1` of SimpleITK and Python 3.7.1) :

```
# Given a sitk image instance -> img

reoriented = sitk.DICOMOrient(img, 'LPS')
```

It is also possible to test multiple permutations of the orientation labels,
check this [doc](https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1DICOMOrientImageFilter.html#details) to understand the about the meaning of the labels.

Comment: Does it also change the metadata to the reoriented value? Like ImageOrientationPatient, PixelSpacing, etc? The doc you reference states "The physical location of all pixels in the image remains the same, but the meta-data and the ordering of the stored pixels may change." does that mean the metadata are updated automatically?